# How is a product of two variables called?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider products of two variables.

> $a^2$

This is called a square.

> $ab$

This is not a square, but it has the same 'dimension'. Is there a more specific name for this expression than *product* that specifies the fact that it is a product of two variables?

(I am not sure that it exists, I was just wondering.)

**Addendum**

I am not thinking in terms of geometry, but in the context of polynomials:

> $a^2+ab+b^2$

Something like "$a^2$ is a *square* and $ab$ is a *mixed square*".

Comment: I think you mean 'variable' rather than 'number'. But not really - perhaps a product of degree $2$?

Comment: Composite number, perhaps?  As opposed to a prime number?

Comment: "binary product" ? But this would be quite misleading!

Comment: @XanderHenderson That only applies if the variables are integers apart from $0,\pm1$. That seems like a large leap in assumptions when what we want it's, as I see it, something more general.

Comment: Area of a rectangle as opposed to area of a square? :)

Comment: Looking at $(a+b)^2 = a^2  + 2ab + b^2$, I'd call $ab$ mixed term. Also, if you think of $a$ and $b$ as variables, this is a polynomial of degree $2$ in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: It is a *unitary bivariate quadratic monomial*. For a more handy name, I would say a *two-product* (an not a *biproduct*).

Comment: @Arthur Indeed, but I can't think of anything in general (other than the area of a rectangle, as suggested above).

Comment: The distinction between $ab$ and $a^2$ in the context of the OP makes sense in the context of dimensional analysis. If $a,b$ have dimensions then the product's dimension is a square. If $a,b$ are dimensionless, then it's possible that $ab=cdf=ghjk$, etc. and it's "bivariate nature" is (possibly) very fluid. So, IMO it often makes more sense to talk about whether the dimensions are a square, cube, power of one, etc., rather than whether the quantity represented by the product is the result of multiplying one, two, three, ... variables together.

Comment: I think they are called "rectangular numbers" in Euclid's *Elements*.

Comment: There is no contemporary single word that is generally understood to mean a product of the form $ab$ where $a$ and $b$ may not be equal.  If it were arising in the middle of a calculation of something like $(a+b)^2/2$ you might call it the cross term, but that is meaningless when considering $ab$ in isolation.  You could say "product of two terms" or (worse, but accurate) "bilinear expression".

Answer (score 2):

In general, in the context of polynomials (e.g. $ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f$)

$ax^2$ and $by^2$ are called quadratic terms or squared terms

$cxy$ rectangular term

$dx$ and $ey$ linear terms

$f$ constant term

Comment: I dont think $cxy$ is called rectangular term. Besides, it is also a quadratic term. Any reference?. I cannot find a single reference on internet calling it "rectangular".

Comment: in fact there are many references. Just one is here https://books.google.com/books?id=jxBGKuFJEHsC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=%22rectangular+term%22&source=bl&ots=DCfvd9kL-J&sig=A3yRB9X1dvJErUVaLPGd6Xlb1mo&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22rectangular%20term%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

$a^n$ is called square and cube, when $n$ is 2 or 3 respectively. These are short names "square of a", "cube of a" for the most common exponentiation operations, being shourtcuts for "a raised to two" and "a raised to three" (winning just 2 syllabes and the concept behind).

There are no names for necesarily all geometrically meaninful operations, such as $\vec a \cdot \vec b$ (area of the paralelogram), $a\cos(\theta)$ (cathetus side), $\pi r^2$ (circle area), $ah/2$ (triangle area).

Perhaps $ab$ (rectangle area) is not enough *simple* to deserve a single word name who summarize it, like "square", "cube", "base", "sector", "area",  etc.

Think on the converse. Which formula should be inequivocally named as "circle" or "triangle"?